# How to pass a value in javaFx Webview html page

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview

Currently I am opening a HTML page in webview. Code is as follows:

```
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.htm");
    webEngine.load( resource.toString() );
    Scene scene = new Scene(webView,width,height);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    System.out.println("Starting the webview....");
    primaryStage.show();
```

I want to display a value in a HTML page. Can anybody suggest me how I can pass a value from above Java code while loading the HTML page.

Comment: Does this help you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: @Alex I don't think that's related. That Q&A is about FXML and how to pass information between various controller instances. The OP has a `WebView` and is looking to manipulate the web page from Java.

Comment: @Manish Look into [`WebEngine#executeScript(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Alex I just want to inject a value which I can print in web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebEngine#executeScript](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript(java.lang.String)) to set any javascript objects or values on the webpage. But you would still need to write custom javascript that reads that value and displays it inside the DOM.
Something along this

```
engine.executeScript("document.getElementByid('myDiv').innerHTML = '" + myValue + "'");
```

A different way if you have full control over the HTML is to parse the HTML with String.replace and replace a placeholder inside your HTML with the value you want to have.

```
String htmlContent = .../* read HTML file as string  */;
webEngine.loadContent(htmlContent.replace("{myVar}", myValue), "text/html");
```

This can get extended with various frameworks such as Apache Commons StringSubstututor
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html

Comment: Tried this but html page is still showing {myVar} it's not getting replaced by myValue

Comment: well you need to place the string {myVar} inside your HTML file :D

Comment: yes this is I have in my html page 
"number: <b>{myVar}</b>"

Comment: ok resource.toString is having filepath istead of content.Let me look into that.

Comment: You need to load the html file as a string and then use .loadContent()